# Как в OSGI (Apache Felix) внедрить АОП для чужих bundle?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Есть необходимость добавить **АОП** для классов из разных бандлов в **OSGI (Apache Felix)**

Нужно создать Aspect и внедрить сквозную функциональность в методы всех имплементации определенного интерфейса.
`(предпочтительно с использованием aspectj)`

Проблема в том, что имплементации интерфейса находятся в разных бандлах и у каждого из них свой собственный ***classpath***.
Из-за этого все классы с имплементациями доступны только в рамках своих бандлов.

Если кто-то сталкивался - PLEASE HELP